# use of b2clogin.com when acquiring token with Client Credential Grant Flow

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

According to [this official Microsoft document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/) (and the documents referenced there) URIs using `login.microsoftonline.com/myTenant/..` must be replaced by `myTenant.b2clogin.com/mytenantId/..`
For the interactive login with MSAL to get an ID token this works fine for me. But I can not figure out which URI to use with `IConfidentialClientApplication` and using a secret. I'm using MSAL 4.18 in a C# Windows application.

The following code works fine using `login.microsoftonline.com`.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    // how must this URL look like when using b2clogin.com
    .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/*MyTenant*.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0")
    .WithClientSecret(secret)
    .Build();

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await app
    .AcquireTokenForClient(scopeArray)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Whatever `b2clogin.com` URI I use (e.g. `https://*myTenant*.b2clogin.com/*myTenantId*/v2.0`)  I get back an `AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance.` response.

What am I missing? Can I continue to use `login.microsoftonline.com` for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer comes with a bit of twists, so please read till end :))

You should not generally continue to use `login.microsoftonline.com` for B2C, [it will be retired on December 4, 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin).

Authority should be in format `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-ID}/{policyname}` or `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/{policyname}`

Also, you should be using `.WithB2CAuthority`, not `.WithAuthority` for B2C in code for client setup (but there is a catch here for your case since it's *Client Credential Grant* which is in the later part of the answer).

[Example code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/tree/jennyf/msal4.12.1) (though the example uses [public client, in your case it's confidential client](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications), just referring it for authority reference).

For details, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#authority-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-and-policy).

But since you are using *Client Credential Grant Flow* using client id and secret, it's not directly supported in B2C as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#current-limitations).

> Although the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow is not currently
> directly supported by the Azure AD B2C authentication service, you can
> set up client credential flow using Azure AD and the Microsoft
> identity platform /token endpoint for an application in your Azure AD
> B2C tenant. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with
> Azure AD enterprise tenants.

In summary, you can not use B2C directly for *Client Credential Grant* and workaround requires to use regular common enterprise AAD backend of B2C. So `b2clogin.com` part would not be applicable for this workaround. That mean only for this particular *Client Credential Flow* case, you should be continuing with `login.microsoftonline.com` since you are not actually using B2C in true sense for this.

Comment: This format of Authority does **not** work with `ConfidentialClientApplication` and using `.WithClientSecret()`. It returns `B2C 'authority' Uri should have at least 3 segments in the path (i.e. https://<host>/tfp/<tenant>/<policy>/...)`

Comment: You should be using `.WithB2CAuthority`, not `.WithAuthority` for B2C  in code for client setup. Added in the answer.

Comment: using `.WithB2CAuthority` fails with `AADB2C90086: The supplied grant_type [client_credentials] is not supported.`

Comment: ok you are using `Client Credential Flow`..That itself is not directly supported in B2C! It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#current-limitations)

Comment: Although the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow is not currently directly supported by the Azure AD B2C authentication service, you can set up client credential flow using Azure AD and the Microsoft identity platform /token endpoint for an application in your Azure AD B2C tenant. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with Azure AD enterprise tenants.

Comment: Can you please update the question mentioning 'Client Credential Grant Flow' explicitly. It's quite possible to miss this part since you did not use that term.

Comment: With the login.microsoftonline.com URI this worked fine, I just dont find a way on how to accomplish the same with b2clogin.com.

Comment: Yes because, in true sense you are NOT using B2C, but the AAD backend of B2C as an workaround for client credential flow.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What do you mean with _b2clogin.com part would not be applicable for this workaround_ ? 'I can not continue to use the existing solution' or 'I don't need to switch to b2clogin.com for this use case' ?

Comment: b2clogin.com is applicable for the user interactive login in B2C. Since yours' is not that case you don't need. Updated answer for more clarity.

Comment: But for your all other scenario of user logins in B2C, you should switch

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue with `Microsoft.Identity.Web` library.
In general the instance is expected to be in this format,

```
 "Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/
```

However it only worked with `login.microsoftonline.com`. With b2clogin it was throwing unknown_instance. After some guessing and looking at recommendations for MSAL and older libraries in other answers, this is what made it work.

```
"Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/tfp/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/<b2c_policy_name>",
```